# Is safe to access to $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] directly?

Tags: php

Is safe to access to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` directly without filtering functions like `filter_input()`?

Comment: short .... yes you can trust $_SERVER['DCOCUMENT_ROOT']

Comment: Surely you mean `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`?

Comment: @Ultimater, yes, thank you, I edited it.

Comment: It's interesting that people are up-voting the comment which says it is a possible duplicate but not voting to close. 10 up-votes on on a close-vote comment but no 4 close-votes

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Not everyone has 3,000 reputation to cast close/reopen votes, but most people have 15 reputation to up-vote a comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`filter_input()` ?

There is no ***input*** in `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, that is a server controlled property and can not be manipulated ordinarily by user input so no need to filter it using that method.

Unless you think your server is compromised that is :) in which case it will be useless to filter for anything at all.